# macOS Catalina WiFi not listing Personal HotSpot

Tags: macos, ios, catalina

The WiFi list should have Personal HotSpot listed above all WiFi connections, now it never appears. (macOS Catalina 10.15.7, iPhone 13 Pro Max iOS 15.5)
[image: No Personal Hotspot listed]

When I turned on "HotSpot Discoverable" on iPhone, it appears as a normal HotSpot on Mac, and ask for password when I click on it. If correct password is given, it connects successfully, but still won't appear before all WiFi, just like a normal HotSpot.

[image: Normal but not Personal]

The Handoff feature works well.

What I've tried:

1. Delete WiFi password from KeyChain.
2. Enable and disable handoff and reboot both devices.
3. Logout and login iCloud account and reboot both devices.
4. Delete and add WiFi network connection on Mac, and reboot.
5. Delete some files under "/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/" and reboot
6. Rename the name of the iPhone
7. "Reset Network Settings" on iPhone.

None of above works.

I also visited the Genius Bar, they said they've got no better solution unless fully recover my macOS, which I don't think this is a proper way.

Comment: Bluetooth needs to be on, on Mac and on iPhone.  Both need to be logged into the same iCloud account.

Comment: Must be something different. I can see wife's iPhone in Personal Hotspots, but not my own. Lost my phone there after a password reset on MacBook.